# Unable to work around thrown exception?

Tags: java, android

This is the code that defines the needed variables

```
public void ProcessInput(View v) {
    Button btn = (Button) v;
    String text = btn.getText().toString();
    String currentInput = inputText.getText().toString();
    int currentInputLen = currentInput.length();
    String evalResult = null;
    double userInputValue = Double.NaN;
```

This is the code i am unable to work around

```
 else if (btn.getText().equals("sqrt")) {

        double LeftVal = Double.parseDouble(currentInput);
        double result = 0;
        if (currentInputLen > 0 && currentInput != "0") {
            result = Math.sqrt(LeftVal);
        }
        inputText.setText(result + "");

 else if (btn.getText().equals("sqr")) {
        if(currentInput.equals(Double.NaN+"") || currentInput.equals(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY+""))
            currentInput = BigDecimal.ZERO+"";
        BigDecimal LeftVal = new BigDecimal(currentInput);
        BigDecimal result = null;
        if (currentInputLen > 0 && LeftVal.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
            result = LeftVal.pow(2);
        }

        inputText.setText(result + "");
    }
```

I calculated 6!, then calculated sininverse(6!) which gave NaN after that when i pressed square button, application crashed.

i wanted to check if current input was invalid by converting double.Nan and double.negative_infinity to string and setting it to zero but it did not work out.What is wrong here.

```
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3607)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3602)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    ... 11 more
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:125)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:362)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:353)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:319)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:350)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:434)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.ProcessInput(MainActivity.java:416)
03-20 18:46:34.951: E/AndroidRuntime(11491):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: If you get an Exception, then you should post the stacktrace here.

Comment: Define "*didn't work*".

Comment: Application was still crashing.

Comment: It's prob. `BigDecimal LeftVal = new BigDecimal(currentInput);` and `currentInput` is null from what I can guess from the stack trace

Comment: Why are you appending "" to BigInteger.ZERO? Why don't you just assign "0" to currentInput?

Comment: What's line 416 of `MainActivity.java` ? Is it indeed `BigDecimal LeftVal = new BigDecimal(currentInput);` ?

Comment: BigDecimal LeftVal = new BigDecimal(currentInput); this is line 416, as you said.

Comment: Then can you post previous code, above the `else` ? Somehow `currentInput` is `"null"`, this is the problem, but we can't know how it becomes null without more code.

Comment: I have edited my post to show what i was calculating that crashed my application.

Comment: You shew another branch of your `if-elseif`, but we can't really see what happens before the crash. Can you post how `currentInput` changes between the initialization you provided (in the first code block) and the branch of the `if` where the crash happens (second code block)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your little workaround to set your `currentInput` to 0 (the little `if` within the `else if`) does not seem to be called, because the following code does not crash:

```
BigDecimal leftVal = new BigDecimal(BigDecimal.ZERO + "");
```

Moreover, the exception shows that you're passing the string `"null"` to the `BigDecimal` constructor, which fails to parse it as a long. Somehow, `currentInput` equals `"null"` at the point you call that constructor. You should try and find where it is assigned this value.

**Note:** `currentInput` is not `null`, but is equal to the string `"null"`.

Comment: Thanx, its working now. I changed my value at sininverse to zero as soon as it became NaN.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out :) Don't forget to upvote/tick the answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing Double values instead of String values... something like:

```
double doubleInput = Double.parseDouble(currentInput);
if (doubleInput == Double.NaN || doubleInput == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
    currentInput = BigDecimal.ZERO.toString();
```

Comment: I posted this answer before seeing the stacktrace update in the question. Anyway, there should be a condition if `currentInput` is null, default it to a valid BigDecimal value e.g. `BigDecimal.ZERO` to avoid the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Rather can converting your `Double` or `BigDecimal` to String, convert your currentInput directly to a `BigDecimal`using the [`BigDecimal(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) constructor

If the input is not parsable to a number it will throw a `NumberFormatException` you will want to catch to force your `BigDecimal.ZERO` value

Moreover, converting numbers to String should be done like this:
`String myDouble = String.valueOf(aDouble)`  (more on that [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28double%29))

Comment: You are right in your suggestions, the OP should do like this. However it does not explain the OP's problem right here.